# Copy A cell in rows of sheet X into a columns on sheet Y

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to figure how I can copy a cell in a row, if a cell next to it has a particular text, in this case Factory 1.

I then want excel to paste all the names into individual columns (Today experimented with some code to add a section where it pastes the name into 3 merged cells).

However I keep getting 1004 error for the last 30min, can someone see if im missing something, it worked fine before.

I tried the following code which had worked before

```
Sub CopyAndListNames()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim employeeRow As Long

    ' Set references to source and destination worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employees") ' Change "SourceSheetName" to the name of your source sheet
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("F1") ' Change "DestinationSheetName" to the name of your destination sheet

    ' Find the last row in the source worksheet
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row in the source worksheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming data starts in row 2
        If wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Factory 1" Then ' Change "Factory Name" to the specific text that indicates a factory name
            ' Copy the employee name from column B to the destination worksheet
            wsSource.Cells(i, 2).Copy wsDestination.Cells(employeeRow, 1)
            ' Merge cells in columns B, C, and D for the employee name
            wsDestination.Range("B" & employeeRow & ":D" & employeeRow).Merge
            ' Increment the employeeRow to skip the merged cells
            employeeRow = employeeRow + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Clean up
    Set wsSource = Nothing
    Set wsDestination = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't initialize `employeeRow` so therefore it starts with `0`. `wsDestination.Cells(employeeRow, 1`  means you want to write something into cell `A0` and that doesn't exist and therefore will raise an error.  Writing `employeeRow = 1` (or whatever is your starting row) should fix this error.

Comment: That's an error, btw, that can be checked easily by using the VBA debugger. Press "Debug" when the error occurs, this shows the line of code where the error occurs. Then you can check the content of all variables.

Comment: You copy the employee name to column A in wsDestination (`wsDestination.Cells(employeeRow,1)` but then merge B:D. I suppose the 1 is supposed to be 2?